# Can the job history be extended?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

For a job which runs every 15 minutes, I see only the last 30 entries. 
I look into SSMS, and I also tried:

```
select * from msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory;
```

I don't see a rule here. Some jobs are tracked for one month, others are tracked for 12 hours only. 
Anyway, can the job history be extended so that I can see all jobs for e.g. one full month back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the SSMS right click the **SQL Server Agent** and select the **Properties**,
in the **History** tab you manage the manage retention of the job history logs
[Also you can see the this tip for more details](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5969/manage-sql-server-agent-history-more-effectively/)